# Random at Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, random

I want to create a query, which give me a list of objects.

But:

- I want to get a list of the entity **jobs**
- A job has a property **entryDate**
- The entity **customer** has many **jobs**
- A customer can have many jobs at the same entryDate

Now I want to create a query, which will give me a list of jobs, but only one entry if there are many entries for a job with the same customer and entryDate. But these entries should be not immediate the same, it should be a random!

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IF statement in your query by using [NativeSqlQuery](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html), or by using HQL's [case when](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html#queryhql-expressions).  Once you get your result list, generate a java Random modded by the list size, and use that entry as your job.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can you post some codes, please?